# Decrement the Variable I'm Incrementing in for loop

Tags: python, list, loops, increment, decrement

kind of a newbie to Python and I've looked around a bit but haven't found a satisfying answer to my question. I'm doing some practice problems and I want to make a method that gets rid of duplicate values in a list. So far, this is my code:

```
def noDouble(nums):
  for x in xrange(len(nums) - 2):
      if nums[x] == nums[x + 1]:
          nums.pop(x)
          x -= 1
  return nums
```

What I want to happen is that if there's a duplicate, pop off one of the duplicates and then move back again (so that if there are, say, 3 instances of the same number, it'll get rid of al of them by 'rewinding').

I'm looking for an explanation for why my code doesn't work as well as an explained solution and I'd really appreciate any and all help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `for` doesn't count numbers; it iterates over a sequence.  Every time the body of the loop executes, `x` is set to the next value produced by the `xrange`.  The `for` statement couldn't care less what `x` is at the end of the loop.

You really shouldn't modify a list within a loop over it, anyway.  The easier way to do this is to build a new list:

```
def remove_doubles(old):
    new = []
    for item in old:
        if new and item == new[-1]:
            continue
        new.append(item)
    return new
```

Of course, the *really* easy way to remove duplicates is `list(set(foo))`.  But that will remove all duplicates, not just adjacent ones, and probably destroy the item order too.

Comment: Note that `set` will give different behavior than what the OP's code seems to be doing.  His approach (if it were to work) is comparing each element only to the next element, so it will only collapse contiguous sequences of duplicates, but `set` will remove all duplicates.  It's not clear what behavior is actually desired here, though.

Comment: `continue` skips to the next run of the loop; `item == new[-1]` checks whether `item` is equal to the last item in the `new` list.

Comment: @Eevee, why is the `new` necessary? Why have the first part of that `and` statement?

Comment: because if `new` is empty, there _is_ no last item to compare to.

Comment: @Eevee, thanks. I didn't know you could just use the name of a list and have that return a boolean (I'm presuming) based on whether or not it contains anything. I chose your answer because of your amazing response. I'm also wondering if there's another way to do this more similar to mine, kind of like Java `for` loops that _don't_ reset counters to ignore changed made to the counter within the loop.

Comment: you can do a boolean test on anything; generally any empty container or zero value will test as false.  and no, you can't.  C-style `for` is just a shorter way to write a `while` loop, and that shortcut doesn't exist in Python, because it's so rarely what you actually want.  you can write it as a `while` if you really want to mess with your loop counter, but there are usually easier ways to do what you want.  (for example, your approach could be made to work by iterating backwards from the end of the list.)

Comment: It may be worth noting the existence of [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). `[val for val, group in groupby(nums)]` builds a new list with any groups of duplicates collapsed into a single occurrence of the element.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand it, the `for` loop isn't a simple increment like it is in C or Java; Python will actually force `x` back to the value it's expected to be for the next loop iteration. So decrementing `x` won't have the effect of adding more loop iterations, because it will be forcibly reset.

```
for x in range(10):
x -= 1
print x
```

will yield

```
-1
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

EDIT: here's a possibility for what you're trying to do, though the accepted answer is easier for your specific use case. Use `while` instead of `for`:

```
limit = len(nums) - 1
x = 0
while x < limit:
  if nums[x] == nums[x+1]:
    nums.pop(x)
    x -= 1
  x += 1
return nums
```

Though this code may still fail with an `IndexError` because of how you're accessing list elements. But still, that's how you'd add extra iterations.

Comment: Java was actually my first language and I was positive this would work based solely on my experiences with Java. Just goes to show how much there is to learn out there. Thanks for the explanation, man/woman. It really cleared things up and gave me some perspective.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the edit. Shouldn't x be incremented within this while loop, though?

Comment: @user3236859 whoops, it sure should.

Comment: thanks again. Sadly, I've already checked off an answer but I wish I could check multiple (even though I don't really know what those checks accomplish).

Comment: @user3236859 the up arrow indicates a useful answer, while the checkmark indicates that a given answer was "the" correct answer that solved your specific issue, or whatever the appropriate analogue is.

Comment: ~~this just got meta~~ Not enough rep to upvote you, but once I accumulate that sweet sweet nectar of the gods that is reputation, I shall return.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you never want to manipulate the counter in a loop (aside from setting it to break out of the loop).  For a similar reason, you don't want to saw a branch you are sitting on, when cutting down a tree :-)

The safer route (compared to nested loops) is to build a set of operations in one loop, then pass this set to a second loop (each loop one level deep).